# How can I output error to a separate file?

Tags: linux, bash, redhat

I'm trying to redirect any errors caught to a log file but failed so far.
function get_info(){

```
local fh="filename.txt"

{
    echo "$(ps aux --forest)\n"
    
}|tee ${fh} > /dev/null #saving output to filename.txt

tar cfz ${fh}.tar.gz ${fh} >& "$error_msg.log" #zipping 'filename.txt' and output error to 'error_msg.log'
```

I am trying get to the the running processes, tar and save the file and do not output on terminal. If it fails, I would like to catch it the "error_msg.log"  While the code is working, I am not catching the error. How can I achieve this?

Comment: I don't understand the logic so it'll be hard for me to provide an answer but putting the number of file descriptor decides what will be piped, `1> stdout.txt` and `2> stderr.txt`.

Comment: Use `"error_msg.log"` instead of `"$error_msg.log"`

Comment: Why are you doing `|tee ${fh} > /dev/null` instead of the simpler `> "$fh"`

Comment: what I understood you want to catch the error in a file while running `tar` without printing the errors on stdout if any errors are coming up then use, `tar cfz ${fh}.tar.gz ${fh} >/dev/null 2>"$error_msg.log"`  (I hope $error_msg.log is a variable for actual file notion)or check the possible errors prior doing `tar` operation e.g. check if `$fh` exists and size >0 then do a `tar`( just merely a suggestion )and BTW you will always have something on the terminal because of your first `echo` while doing `ps -aux`